# Is it possible to access the contents of a list created in a separate class? C#

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-entities

Question: How can I access the list people in a separate class with a method that wants to read in the politicalAffiliation, phoneNumber, address of each row in the list? I used the term "row" because the list is populated from the linq to entities query of the db table.

here is an example:

```
public partial class Person  //class comes from entity framework. Data table Person which has several fields (i.e. fname, lname, politicalAffiliation, phoneNumber, address)
{

  public static List<Person> GetInfoForPerson (string fname)
  {
   List<Person> person;
   using (PeopleDBEntities ctx = new PeopleDBEntities())
   {
    person = (from p in ctx.Person
              where p.fName == fname
              select p).ToList();
   }
   return person;
 }
}     


class ManagePerson
{
 private bool GetDefinedInfoForPersonFromFname(person)
 {
  List<Person> people = Person.GetInfoForPerson(Martha);
  if (people.count == 0) 
   {return false;}
  if (people.count !=0) 
   {return true;}
 }
}

class AccessPerson
{
 protected void ConnectWithPerson(Person person)
  {
 // here is where I want to access the list people from the ManagePerson class
 //I want to be able to iterate over the list in order to search for certain 
 //values of fname and lname
 // in order to use the values of political affiliation, phoneNumber, and address 
 //associated with the particular fname and lname match 
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to expose the list as a property

Comment: no it is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it a public member of the owning class.

Comment: so simple. Thank you - this did work for giving me access to the list.

Comment: Great! Please mark this as the solution to the question so that the site can view this post as resolved.

Comment: Jeffrey Wieder - can you help with iterating through the list...?

Comment: You just need to loop through. foreach(Person p in person)

Comment: Jeffrey Wieder - I am familiar with the foreach loop. The actual problem is much harder to explain than the generic data I put in the question.   I need to "test" the values of each row in the list, and when one works, stop iterating through the list. I am trying to make a connection to a specific device by using the data from the table

Comment: @user3486667 You can `break` out of the loop when a condition is met. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you should  do the following  steps

make this public

```
 public  class ManagePerson
{
```

and property like this

```
   public List<Person> Persons
            {get{return people;} 
              set{ people=value;}}
```

and last

```
 List<Person> people; //should be at level class 
private bool GetDefinedInfoForPersonFromFname(person)
 {
        people= Person.GetInfoForPerson(Martha);
```